# How do I centre y axis?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm making a program which draws a graph, using the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization namespace, but when I plot a graph, [enter it ends up looking like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvX11.png)

There are two things wrong with it:
1)The y axis isn't in the middle
2)The intervals are all wrong and are arbitrary.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

In the designer properties:

- Select ChartAreas
- Select your ChartArea
- Select Axes
- Select XAxis
- Configure the properties to suit. You should look at the labels + interval categories and Minimum + Maximum values on the Scaling category (for centering).

Comment: I've managed to centre it sort of, but the y axis is still at the left side, making the graph difficult to read.

Comment: I fixed it by using the Crossing setting under Scale. Thanks for the help!